# Process pandas group efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df with columns a,b,c,d and e. What I want is, group by df on the basis of a,b and c. And tthen for each group I want to remove NULL value of column d and e with most frequent value of that column in that group. And then finally drop duplicates for each group.

I am doing the following procesing:

```
        final_df = pd.DataFrame()
        grouped = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        for _, group in grouped:
            group = group.replace('', np.nan)
            group = group.fillna(group.mode().iloc[0])
            group.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
            final_df = pd.concat([rows_to_insert, final_df])
```

But the iteration is making my processing really very slow. Can someone suggest me better way to do it?

Sample input:

```
a   b   c   d       e
a1  b1  c1  NULL    e2
a2  b2  c2  NULL    NULL
a2  b2  c2  NULL    NULL
a1  b1  c3  d4      e4
a1  b1  c1  NULL    e2
a1  b1  c1  d1      e2
a1  b1  c1  d1     NULL
```

Sample output:

```
a   b   c   d         e
a1  b1  c1  d1      e2
a2  b2  c2  NULL    NULL
a1  b1  c3  d4      e4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `groupby().mode` with a catch when the data is all `NaN`:

```
def get_mode(series):
    out = series.mode()
    return out.iloc[0] if len(out) else np.nan

df.groupby(['a','b','c'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(get_mode)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c    d    e
0  a1  b1  c1   d1   e2
1  a2  b2  c2  NaN  NaN
2  a1  b1  c3   d4   e4
```

And if you want to fill your original dataframe with the mode:

```
df[['d','e']] = df.groupby(['a','b','c']).transform(get_mode)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c    d    e
0  a1  b1  c1   d1   e2
1  a2  b2  c2  NaN  NaN
2  a2  b2  c2  NaN  NaN
3  a1  b1  c3   d4   e4
4  a1  b1  c1   d1   e2
5  a1  b1  c1   d1   e2
6  a1  b1  c1   d1   e2
```